# Python cv2.boost() error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I was working on Computer Vision in Python. I have to use the AdaBoost algorithm for a purpose.

OpenCV has a function :

```
cv2.Boost([trainData, tflag, responses[, varIdx[, sampleIdx[, varType[, missingDataMask[, params]]]]]])
```

which I used like this: `model = cv2.Boost(X,cv2.CV_ROW_SAMPLE,Y)`
where X is the training data and Y is the response

This is the error which shows up: `module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'Boost'`

I tried searching for relevant documentation which indexes the function Boost but this error keeps showing up which make no sense

I'm using OpenCV version 3.2.0 and Python version 3.6.1

Comment: It looks like `Boost` no longer has a Python wrapper for OpenCV 3.0+. The [documentation for 3.0](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html) has no Python call syntax, and neither does the parent [`DTrees`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/decision_trees.html) from which it's derived.